# Does Axios post call mutate the parameter?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an `entry` object:

```
entry = {
 name:"Jakob", 
 surname:"Laurence",
 age:"25"
}
```

Is it possible that a call to:

```
axios.post('http://host/myurl/myservice/', self.entry)
```

will mutate the `entry` object?

And if it is (possible), is it enough to use

```
copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self.entry))
axios.post('http://host/myurl/myservice/', copy)
```

to avoid the mutation?

The thing is that I have noticed some strange behavior in my project,
and I just came up with the idea that it could be caused by mutation.

Unfortunately I cannot test my theory right now - So, that's why I am asking...

Thanks.

Comment: axios.post won't mutate it on its own, but its possible to write interceptors which would mutate it.

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks for the reply.  That's bad news for me :(  ... I am just calling the post 'as is' from  inside of my Vuejs project - As I understand from your reply it probably does not mutate the 'entry'...then the problem must reside somewhere else...

Comment: @Plirkee I am inferring based on your code snippet that you would probably benefit from writing this solution in a more functional style. Doing so would basically eliminate the types of errors that come from mutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. If you are really worried that it is you can use the spread operator to copy the data.

```
const copy  =  {...self.entry}
axios.post('http://host/myurl/myservice/', copy)
```